# Monitor Services with $ in the service name in Icinga / Nagios

Tags: monitoring, service, icinga

I'm trying to set up monitoring on a couple of MSSQL instances that exist on my Windows servers. The issue here is that if the service name contains a `$` (for example, `MSSQL$PROD`)then the check_nt command will return a warning of null.

The following is an example of what I have in `windows.cfg`

```
define service{
        use                     generic-service
        host_name               SERVERNAME
        service_description     MSSQL Service
        check_command           check_nt!SERVICESTATE!-d SHOWALL -l MSSQL$PROD
        }
```

I have tried surrounding the service name with " " (which works with services with spaces) and putting a backslash before the $ in the service name with no luck. Does anyone know if this can be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to escape the `$` with another `$` and single-quote the name:

```
define service{
        use                     generic-service
        host_name               SERVERNAME
        service_description     MSSQL Service
        check_command           check_nt!SERVICESTATE!-d SHOWALL -l 'MSSQL$$PROD'
        }
```

alternatively you can omit the single quotes by using `MSSQL\$$PROD`. I like the first call more ;)

Answer (score 1):

Krissi has the right answer.

I just want to mention an option which might be easier to parse: change your command definition to take another `$ARG$`, whereupon the complexity of this sort of escaping is handled in your command definition instead of in each service.  So now your service looks like:

```
check_command    check_nt!SERVICESTATE!-d SHOWALL -l MSSQL!PROD
```

and in your commands.cfg:

```
command_line     /path/to/commmand --someopt value1 $ARG1$"$$"$ARG2$
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to "quote" it and double up the $ sign for some reason.

For example the service name for Windows Internal Database is "MSSQL$MICROSOFT##SSEE".

My check_command:

```
check_command           check_nt_srv!MSSQL"$$"MICROSOFT\#\#SSEE
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the answers above to no avail, and am also trying to monitor SQL Server instances.  Now, in 2017, it appears that NOT doubling up the $ works, as long as you maintain the quotes:

`check_nt -H xx.xx.xx.xx -s "" -p 12489 -v SERVICESTATE -l 'MSSQL$BLAHBLAH' -d SHOWALL`