# omd nagios monitoring servicestate mssql / Failed to open service

Tags: sql-server, nagios, omdistro

I'm trying to monitor mssql service in OMD nagios, but with no success so far. 
Communication port: 1433
instance name is like: MSSQL$instance

Here's my check:

```
check_command check_nt!SERVICESTATE!-l 'MSSQL$$instance' (like you've suggested here http://serverfault.com/questions/517291/monitor-services-with-in-the-service-name-in-icinga-nagios, nagios said: Failed to open service: MSSQL)
```

I've tried some other combinations:
MSSQL\$$instance (Failed to open service: MSSQL\$SQL2012)
MSSQL"$$"instance (Failed to open service: MSSQL"$"SQL2012)
"MSSQL"$$"instance" (Failed to open service: "MSSQL"$"SQL2012")

Any suggestions very appreciated.
Don't know what causes the problem. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried doublequotes and the literal string?check_snmp_win!!"MSSQL$KNXDB52"!$USER2$!1 is a working check on my server, although I am checking via SNMP directly.

Comment: Try just MSSQL$$instance, no quotes

Comment: @Keith: unfortunately MSSQL$$instance gives: Failed to open service: MSSQL$instance. Maybe I just try to use check via SNMP as TheFiddlerWins suggested. However I'd like to check it via servicestate - there must be some way ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I add -d SHOWALL to my check command, so it's like:

```
check_command check_nt!SERVICESTATE!-d SHOWALL -l MSSQL\\$$instance
```

then nagios (in check_mk) shows: No service/process specified

Do you know what can cause this problem?

#### Solution

Finally I've found the soultion. It turns out the problem was in check_nt command definition.
Oryginally I've used it like this:

```
define command {
    command_name    check_nt
    command_line    /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_nt -H '$HOSTADDRESS$' -v '$ARG1$' -p 12489 '$ARG2$'
}
```

And that causes above problems with "No service/process specified" and "failed to open service" .
When I change my check_nt definition to:

```
define command {
    command_name    check_nt
    command_line    /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_nt -H $HOSTADDRESS$ -v $ARG1$ -p 12489 $ARG2$
}
```

it works like a charm :) with:

```
check_command       check_nt!SERVICESTATE!-d SHOWALL -l MSSQL"$$"instance
```

So the problem finally resolved :)
Kind regards

Answer (score 1):

I had to trial and error this one.  What works for me is

```
MSSQL\\$Instance
```

as in

```
check_command           check_nt!SERVICESTATE!-d SHOWALL -l MSSQL\\$Instance
```

Comment: MSSQL\\$Instance gives another monit: Failed to open service: MSSQL\$SQL2012$. There must be a way to do it via check_nt!SERVICESTATE! - still searching for the answear. Thanks to all for sugestions!